# Передать файл и строку в одном AJAX запросе

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

Функция отправки:

```
 function send(xml) {  //отправка данных на сервер    
                var file_data = $('#sortpicture').prop('files')[0];
                var form_data = new FormData();
                form_data.append('file', file_data);
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: '/Home/Form',  
                    data: { xml: xml},form_data,
                    success: function (responce) {
                        SaveToLocal("s",xml);// префикс s - sended
                        notification("Данные успешно отправлены", "success");
                    },
                error: function (xhr, str) {
                        SaveToLocal("u", xml);// префикс u - unsended
                        notification("Подключение недоступно, данные сохранены в локальном хранилище", "warning");
                        setTimeout(DelayResend, 30 * 1000);// функция отложенной отпраки с тайм аутом 30 сек.
                    }
                })

        }; - строка передается в параметре, а файл - из формы.
```

Контроллер, в который передаю:

```
 [HttpPost]
    [ValidateInput(false)]
    public void Form(string xml)

    {

        if (Request.Files.Count != 0)
        {
            string fileName = "";
            if (Request.Browser.Browser.Contains("InternetExplorer"))
                fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(Request.Files[0].FileName);
            else
                fileName = Request.Files[0].FileName;

            string filePath = string.Format("~/images/{0}", fileName);
            Request.Files[0].SaveAs(Server.MapPath(filePath));
        }

        string mydocpath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
        using (StreamWriter outputFile = new StreamWriter( @"\WriteLines.txt",true))
        outputFile.WriteLine(xml);
    }
```

строка передается, файл нет. И так и эдак крутился. Получатся передать либо файл либо строку.

Comment: Заголовок либо файл, либо строка. Если файл - картинка, можно в base64, а если другой тип, тогда вопрос можно ли передать файл как строку

Answer (score 0):

Добавь строку в form-data:

```
form_data.append('xml', xml);
```

Если и после этого она не попала в параметр xml контроллера, то ее всегда можно получить так:

```
string xml = null;
foreach (var key in Request.Form.AllKeys)
{
    if (key == "xml")
        xml = Request.Form.Get(key);
}
```